# Is there an order to the 6 daily remembrances?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, prayer-book, memory

In my siddur I find a list of 6 daily remembrances. But they seem to be out of order, for example Sabbath is last when it was commanded before the incident with Miriam. Is there a reason for this order or is that just the way it was printed?

http://www.tumms.org/six_remembrances.htm

Comment: Please [edit] in why you think the list is out of order.

Comment: as I mentioned sabbath is listed last, when it was commanded before the incident with Miriam

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make it as clear as you can. Comments can be deleted at any time, so please don't rely on them to clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

[Siddur Rabenui Hazakain 198](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&st=&pgnum=227&hilite=) says that the order is based on the way it is mentioned in Ahavas Olam and Kriyas Shema.

> First is Yetziyas Mitzrayim which is the entire basis of Kriyas Shema.
>
> Second is Har Sinai for the words Uvanu Bacharta
>
> Third is Amalek for the words Lshimcha Hagadol
>
> Fourth is Aigel for the words Uliyachedcha Bahava
>
> Fifth is Miriam for the words Lehodos Lecha
>
> Sixth is Shabbos for the words Uzechartem Es Kol Mitzvos Hashem

He leaves it at the end that the question still remains as to why it is in the order of Birchas Kriyas Shema. Also on the notes on the bottom he questions that this only works according to this Nusach and not according to other Nusachs that say the words in a different order.